# "Where can I buy X?"

Tags: discussion, scope

[This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/317/22) asks where to buy a fairly obscure movie.  Are these questions on-topic?  Finding an old/obscure film can be very frustrating sometimes, so I can see a clear appeal to being able to ask such questions. But that alone does not make the question on-topic for our new site.

Answer (score 5):

I think an answer to this question has no lasting value. It doesn't matter if the movie is a blockbuster or some fairly unknown movie. If a answer gives a shop, this will be too localized as the shop can be unavailable from different countries and be closed in two years. So I think that shouldn't be allowed (closed as too localized).

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason this site should be unique in it's stance on purchasing recommendations - to my knowledge, no other site allows it, and I don't see an argument for it here.

I recommend the policy of "close it and refer them to chat," considering we don't want to leave them stranded (and many users here will likely have a good recommendation for them).

Comment: This is different from a purchasing recommendation because it's not soliciting opinions on which products or vendors are "good."  Now, if it was asking "Should I buy my movies from Amazon, B&N, or Blockbuster?" then _that_ would be a bad-subjective question that should be closed.

Comment: (Note that I'm not making an argument for this being on-topic; I'm simply pointing out what I see is the difference between normal shopping recommendation questions, and this one)

Answer (score 3):

Like others have said it is too localized. But perhaps there could be a wiki page for known websites that stock rare movies?